# Read Aloud EPUB3 Authoring Tools

Tags: epub3, google-play-books

I am trying to add the read-aloud feature to my children's books to help the children to read. I have tried many tools, CircularFlo, PubCoder, Kotobee, etc.

The EPUB3 generated with CircularFlo and PubCoder work perfectly with the read-aloud feature on Apple Books but not Google Books. I spoke to CircularFlo tech team online and know that the software doesn't support Google Books yet.

I spent many days looking into different app but have had no luck on that. Does anybody have any authoring tools to recommend?

The read-aloud book should allow to use author's own narration and have the word highlighted when it is being read. For example, please refer to this eBook on Google Play Books.

Any helps or suggestions given is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Cheekian